# Unwanted explicit link target in JQuery UI button

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, button, hyperlink

I am defining a link to the home page in my HTML as following:

```
<div id="hb"><a id="but_home" href="index.html">Home</a></div>
```

I set the JQuery UI button layout (and position) as following:

```
$(thisPage.hash('hb')).button().css({
    width: 100,
    top:300,
    left:60,
    position:"absolute"
});
```

and I get:

[image]

Why is `(index.html)` displayed and how to get rid of it? And, is the above the right way create a JQuery UI button?

Comment: What's `thisPage.hash()` doing?

Comment: It just adds a '#' before 'hb' -> '#hb'

Comment: Well, if I add the hash myself, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/SPnZR/ -- your jQuery UI code looks fine, I would suggest looking at that `thisPage.hash` method.

Comment: The link works fine... It's the layout the issue !!!

Comment: Your code sample isn't responsible for the text or colors, just the positioning. Therefore, it's impossible to help you using the data provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying it.  I'm not sure exactly why you're using thisPage.hash(), however, it appears to not be returning exactly what you'd expect.  Try just using the select identifier:

```
$('#hb').button().css({
    width: 100,
    top:300,
    left:60,
    position:"absolute"
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have another javascript library or file on the page that could be conflicting?  On a side note, ordinarily, when I do buttons, I use either a `<button>` element, or an `input` tag.

Comment: I am developing a generic page and there is only a 'work-in-progress' image above the button.

Comment: So, no other javascript files included on the page then?  What versions of jquery and jquery-ui are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.7.1.min and jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min

Comment: Weird, when I mock it up with the exact code above on jsFiddle, only including those two libraries, it works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/5MJZC/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6363/discussion-between-jverstry-and-prioritymark)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution (though I still don't know what caused the issue in the first place):

```
<div id="hb">
    <form action="index.html"><input type="submit" id="but_hb" value="Home"></form>
</div>
```

...

```
$('#but_hb').button();
$('#hb').css({
    width: 100,
    top:300,
    left:60,
    position:"absolute"
});
```